# Shouldn't an NSTableview autoresize when its superview resizes?

Tags: xcode, macos, nstableview, autoresize, subviews

I have an NSTableview on the contentview of an NSWindow.  When I resize the window, I would like the height of the NSTableview to resize.  This isn't working.

To make sure I haven't set something incorrectly, I created a new mac project, view-based, storyboard.  In IB, I added an NSTableView to the view.  It looks like the default is to have autoresizing on, so I made no changes.  Run this sample project, resize the window and the tableview does not resize.  I guess I am missing something.  What is it??

BTW, I am using xCode 6.3

Comment: BTW, this doesn't seem to work with an NSView either.  I just added an NSView to the NSWindow contentView and it doesn't resize either when I resize the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• While viewing the xib, select the Bordered Scroll View that contains your table.

• In the lower-right of the xib canvas, you'll see 4 icons.  The 2nd icon is called "Pin" if you hover your mouse over it.  Click that.

• In the view that pops up, click the 4 red constraint connectors, then click "Add 4 Constraints".

Comment: Thanks, that put me into the right direction.  Most of the constraints were disabled and none red, but but control clicking from the scrollview to the superview I was able to add the correct top and bottom constraints to get the effect I needed.